# using sudo always prompt for password when calling rsync

Tags: linux, bash, sudo, rsync

I have a program that repeatedly uses `rsync` to send data to the destination, the `rsync` script which the program uses doesn't need a password to send data as I've used a public-key authentication mechanism for `rsync`. but the program needs to be run with `sudo` as it uses some kernel utilities too, but what is happening is whenever I use `sudo` to run the program it always prompts for password input when calls `rsync` script.

Is there a way to mitigate this problem?

Comment: Probably. Is there a way to make your question clearer? What are "some kernel utilities"? What does your script look like?

Comment: @waltinator it uses `qdiscs` utility of the kernel. the `qdiscs` are present in netlink library.

Comment: my script contains a `rsync` command to send data from source to destination. it can be used to send data to destination without using `sudo` or entering destination's password, but when i'm using it with `sudo` it always prompts for password.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might not be the administrator of this server, and the admin have setup this to improve security. In case you are the admin you can follow the steps below else you can ask directly the admin to make the changes.

So what you can do :

***In case your it asks you to enter your user PASSWORD :***

1- Get your username & group id (gid) :

```
id
```

2- Check in sudo configuration file :

```
grep <username> /etc/sudoers
grep <gid> /etc/sudoers
```

You must see an entry for the group if the line is beginning with % ; else an entry for your username without % symbol :

```
%<gid>  ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

Execute visudo to edit /etc/sudoers :

```
visudo
```

Now you should add (*NOPASSWD:*) to make sudo not asks for your user password  :

```
%<gid>  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

***In case your it asks you to enter the root PASSWORD :***
Execute visudo to edit /etc/sudoers :

```
visudo
```

Delete the line above to disable rootpw flag on /etc/sudoers, so you will not be asked to enter the root password :

```
Defaults rootpw
```

Comment: Hi, I did this already but for a single user only didn't make any group. but again the question is even with this configuration/setting we have to use sudo which comes back to the original problem, that using sudo with Rsync requires a password, with your suggested solution sudo was necessay but it doesn't required password to proceed.

Comment: i think you have to make tour question more clearer, or share little snippet of your rsync code. are you using rsync to transfer file through networl ?